# Can redefining a namespace name in the same scope break the ODR rule?

Tags: c++, namespaces

on C++ primer ch 18. namespaces:

> "As with any name, a namespace name must be unique within the scope in which the namespace is defined. Namespaces may be defined at global scope or inside
> another namespace. They may not be defined inside a function or a class."

But as I guess if not wrong; defining a namespace more than once in the same scope wouldn't break ODR but instead reopens that namespace and may add to it.

Here is my example:

```
namespace fooNS{
    int x = 5;
}

namespace fooNS{
    int y = 10;
}


int main(){

    std::cout << fooNS::x << '\t' << fooNS::y << '\n';

}
```

- My code works fine so what is meant with "As with any name, a namespace name must be unique within the scope in which the namespace is defined."?
- So are there some situations where redefining the same namespace will break the ODR rule? Thanks!

Comment: Namespaces aren't compilable units, so by themselves, they aren't really part of the rule.

Comment: You can even add to the `std` namespace, but only in very few well-specified [extensions points](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std).

Comment: @Eljay: Yes but some standard library template types specializations only like `std::hash<>`. Otherwise the behavior is Undefined. right?

Comment: More to the point, the standard C++ library header files open and re-open the `namespace std` all the time.

Comment: _"...Multiple namespace blocks with the same name are allowed. All declarations within those blocks are declared in the named scope...."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace

Comment: It is not possible to use the name of a namespace for something else, in the same scope.    For example, it is not possible to have a namespace named `foo` and a declaration of a type named `foo` visible to the compiler in the same scope.

Comment: @Peter Got it now what is meant in the book. Thank you!

Comment: @Maestro A namespace's name is implicitly unique within its scope. In any situation where it seems like you might have two different namespaces with the same name in the same scope, you would actually just have one namespace with that name being referred to twice.